# Javascript timstamp function one liner

Tags: javascript

In java this is my one liner to create a timestamp function with flexible formats:

```
String timestamp() {
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  return String.format("%1$ty%1$tm%1$td_%1$tH%1$tM%1$tS", now);
}
```

What is the equivalent in javascript? 
Here is JSFiddle for it: [jsfiddle.net/9kpea998](https://jsfiddle.net/9kpea998/)

(Yes I know there is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/))

Comment: I think, we should make a comment mandatory for a downvote. Dont know what is happening.

Comment: @xyz, Exactly!!! It's like saying "you're doing something wrong, improve it" without saying __what__ is wrong.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, OP doesnt know that. Without telling him what mistake he made, its going to take him time to realize his mistakes. When I was getting started with SO, I used to get a lot of downvotes and also a lot of useful comments. Nowadays, I only see downvotes, everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler solution using the lowest amount of code is:

```js
function timestamp() {
    return new Date().toISOString();
}

document.write(timestamp());
```

but you don't have access to custom formatting.

If you want the exact formatting used in the question, you could use this longer version:

```js
function timestamp() {
    var date = new Date();

    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    var second = date.getSeconds();

    year = year.toString().substr(2);
    month = ("00" + month).substr(-2,2);
    day = ("00" + day).substr(-2,2);

    var timestamp =
        year + month + day + "_" +
        hour + minute + second;

    return timestamp;
}

document.write(timestamp());
```

**Edit:**

You can use regex to format the standard `ISO` string a little more like this:

```js
function timestamp() {
    return new Date().toISOString().replace(/([-:]|\..+)/g, "").replace("T", "_");
}

document.write(timestamp());
```

Comment: Many thanks! But no very flexible. No ideas for something in the middle ground? Eg. function timestamp() { return (new Date).toISOString().replace(/:/gi,'-') };